# Android - How to restart activity ( or bring it to front ) on pause

Tags: android, android-intent, onpause

i'm developing an app for tablet ( android 4.0.3 ) that must go in public places ( resturant, bar etc.. ).

What i need to do is to block users to go out the application so i override method `onPause` to restart activity when application goes to background (Example: Home pressed )

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RivendesiActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My problem is that when i click home button, application restart but only after 3-4 seconds.. so user has the time to click on applications buttons->settings and if there.. i don't know why.. my application doesn't restart. How can i fix? Thanks!

Comment: I have same question. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to disable the home key effect by adding the following to your activity.

```
@override
public void onAttachedToWindow(){  
   this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
   super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

P.S. this approach is not recommended and is against the normal behavior of an activity. So use it when you mean it :)

Comment: 10-14 22:27:26.896: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.

Comment: is too long.. what part you need to see?

Comment: which android version are you using?

Comment: 4.0.. android:minSdkVersion="14"

Comment: ahaaan, unfortunately this technique is no longer functional in ICS and above. Sorry I didn't notice that you mentioned this in your question

Comment: i don't want to disable home key.. but i want to restart app ( fastly ) when app go in background.. my method works but is not too fast

Comment: perhaps off-load the heavy lifting of things you might be in onCreate, onStart, onResume to an AsyncTask.